# Why not write data mariadb database in aws server

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services

I have installed a panel on the AWS server. I transferred my website to AWS from Namecheap shared hosting. when I transferred my website to AWS website work normally without a withdrawal page. Then I tried in XAMPP server and it works fine. It doesn't write data in the database on AWS server.

```
<?php 
        include('config.php');
        session_start();
        $uid=$_SESSION['user']['user_id'];
        date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Dhaka');
        $date=date("Y-m-d h:i");
        $status=1;

        $statement290 = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_member WHERE user_id=?");
        $statement290->execute(array($uid));
        $result290 = $statement290->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        foreach ($result290 as $row290){
        $wcredit=$row290['credit'];
        }
        $amount=$_POST['withdraw_amount']+10;
        
    if  
        ($amount >= $wcredit)
        {
        $status=0;
        echo json_encode(array("wstatues"=>"<div role='alert' class='alert alert-danger'>
        <strong>Your withdraw amount is more than your balance!</strong>
        </div>"));
        }
    else if 
        ($amount < 500)
        {
        $status=0;
        echo json_encode(array("wstatues"=>"<div role='alert' class='alert alert-danger'>
        <strong>Minimum withdraw 500tk !</strong>
        </div>"));
        }
    if ($status==1){

        $state = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_member WHERE user_id=?");
        $state->execute(array($uid));
        $results = $state->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        foreach ($results as $row) {
            $credit = $row['credit'];
        }
        $final_amount = $credit-$_POST['withdraw_amount'];
        $statement = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE tbl_member SET credit=? WHERE user_id=?");
        $statement->execute(array($final_amount,$uid));
        $a="0";
        $statement = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl_withdraw (request_by, amount, method, send_to, account_type, date, withdraw_status) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
        $statement->execute(array($uid,$_POST['withdraw_amount'],$_POST['withdraw_method'],$_POST['withdraw_to'],$_POST['account_type'],$date,$a));

        echo json_encode(array("wstatues"=>"<div role='alert' class='alert alert-success'>
            <strong>Your withdraw has been successfully requested!</strong>
            </div>"));
        $id = $pdo->lastInsertId();
        $detail="Withdraw Request By You";
        $date=date("Y-m-d h:i");
        $type="Withdraw-R";
        $statement2 = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl_transaction 
        (detail_id, type, description,transaction_date,user_balance)
        VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)");
        $statement2->execute(array($id,$type,$detail,$date,$final_amount));
        }
?>
```

Comment: Did you check for  [PDO errors](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php) to see why your queries are not working?

Comment: All insert fails or which? `$date` is not a mysql date version, are you trying to put that in a datetime column?